# Is there an equivalent to the C# "var" keyword in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, type-inference

In C#, I like the `var` keyword for situations like this:

```
var myList = new List<MyType>();
```

Is there any equivalent in C++/CLI, or do I have to repeat the type name everytime just like this:

```
List<MyType ^>^ myList = gcnew List<MyType ^>();
```

Could not find an explicit statement in the docs or by Google so far. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

*Addendum from 2022:* as the accepted answer states correctly, today there is the `auto` keyword. We are now using this for years, and it works flawlessly for both managed and unmanaged types.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I never realized how much `List<MyType ^>^` seems to include a very happy emoticon.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2008 there is no such equivalent.  However with Visual Studio 2010 you can use the `auto` keyword to implement `var` like semantics in C++.  I know this works with non-managed C++ and I'm fairly certain it works for C++/CLI as well.

Comment: This is a feature in C++0x, is it not?

Comment: Yes, this is a feature of C++0x.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I seem to recall that C++0x features would *not* get ported to C++/CLI at this point. They just don't have the resources atm. In the long run, it'll definitely be added to C++/CLI, but I don't think it'll be in VS2010. I could be wrong though, this is just what I recall reading on the VCTeam blog.

Comment: No it's not, because C++0x sounds better, and has the advantage that everyone is used to the name, and knows what it refers to.

Comment: @Yacoder: in addition to what jalf said, we can also move to hex and call it C++0A if it gets approved this year

Comment: @jalf: 0x vs 1x... Now the committee is going to discuss that question for about one-two more years =)

Answer (score 13):

I know that type inference is envisioned in the [C++1x standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B1x#Type_inference):

```
auto someStrangeCallableType = boost::bind(&SomeFunction, _2, _1, someObject);
auto otherVariable = 5;
```

Currently, AFAIK, there is no equivalent.

Comment: the *code* *name* of the next standard is still c++0x, even if we have 2010 already.

Answer (score 4):

C++ has typedef. Just alias those hairy types with a typedef, and use the friendly name.

No, there's no "var" keyword. Vaguely recall there's something to that effect in boost.

Comment: Well, typedef may help sometimes, but, for example, a "typedef List<MyType^>^ ListMyType" does not gain much.

Comment: You could typedef it to something shorter, like just `list`. It doesn't have to be a globally unique name, just unique in the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 3):

C++0x is going to have an auto keyword: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1705.pdf

Comment: <nitpick> auto is already a keyword. they just recycled it. </nitpick>

Comment: @Simon_Weaver used to define the scope of a variable as being to the end of the current block.