# *var* keyword for C++CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I would like to store a row of a database data into an object but I don't know whether there exists to be a **var** like keyword found similarly in C#. Because I would like to retrieve the whole row data not any specific column alone.

C#:

```
var data=from t in TableX 
         where t.id==100
         select t;
```

Comment: The most similar thing to `var` is `auto`.

Comment: auto won't be enough to get the LINQ to work.

Comment: @JimBalter Do you mean C++/CLI `auto` will not do that either? Or just that C++11 `auto` is not enough?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi About being duplicate: I think that question is not up to date any more... C++11 was not finished, and Visual Studio 2012 was not released back then.

Comment: @hyde, why are the answers the same, then? :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Well, what is answer? `auto` or "no, you can't do that LING thing in C++/CLI"?

Comment: @hyde, three answers out of four say `auto`, so `auto` it is I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ /CLI there is the `auto` keyword having the same meaning as `var` in C#.

```
auto data=...
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007976/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-var-keyword-in-c-cli).